# Problems with quadratures

Tags: triangles, matlab, gaussian-integral, finite-element-method

I'm having issues when computing quadrature, and probably there is something I do not get theoretically. I looked everywhere, but no one seems to explain in a good way the problem

I have a simple triangle, with coordinates `[[(0, 0); (1, 0); (0, 1)]]`

Over this domain I want to compute the integral of $x^2$.

Doing it by hand and wolfram, the result is $0.16$.
With quadrature is half the value. I tried different points and weights but the result is always the same. I use the following:

```
p = [(0.16666666666667, 0.16666666666667),
     (0.16666666666667, 0.66666666666667),                                    
     (0.66666666666667, 0.16666666666667)]
w = [1/6, 1/6, 1/6]
```

The formula I use is

```
res = 0;

for i = 1:size(p,1)
```

$res = res + f(p_i) * f(p_i)  * w_i;$

```
end

value = res;
```

where $f(x,y) = x$

Comment: Can you rewrite your formula in mathematical notation? I don't understand things like $f(p(i,:))$

Comment: probably now it is better

Comment: well you integrate constants correctly at least. is it true for linear polynomials? What happens when you up the number of points?

Comment: for linear and constant it seems ok, here I seem to have this problem

Comment: OK, i think its the number of points then, I only remember 1D  quadratures, and there I think you need n+1 points to integrate degree n exactly, in higher dimensions this should get worse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the constant integrand one, the weights sum to $\dfrac12$, which is the correct area.

---

The true integral is

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}x^2\,dy\,dx=\int_0^1 x^2(1-x)\,dx=\frac1{12}.$$

The numerical estimate,

$$\frac16\left(\frac1{36}+\frac1{36}+\frac4{9}\right)=\frac1{12}.$$

Comment: but the triangle has total area 1/2, and the weights work for constant functions? (I'm rusty)

Comment: @CalvinKhor: you are right, my bad. I was thinking of the average value.

Comment: I start to believe that I worte badly in wolfram. So to understand, since the area is 1/2, the weights must sum to 1/2, so that the result of integrating the constant function 1 is 1/2 ? And thus with those weights, my formula for quadrature is then correct, with result of 1/12?

Comment: @Cla: double check the integral by hand.

Comment: Yes also by hand is 1/12, sorry for creating the problem in the beginning! Just a thing: I then can say that 3 points for a quadratic function on a 2D domain are enough?

Comment: @cla: it takes six points to exactly reconstruct a quadric. I guess that you were lucky.

Comment: Ok i'll increment my points to be sure. Thank you so much again! PS do you have a suggestion for  reference to undestand well quadrature, how many points are needed based on dimension and functions, ecc.. ?